# Haskell find divisors based on comprehension method

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I need a little help understanding a comprehension method function.

```
compdivides :: Integer -> [Integer]
compdivides x
    | x > 0 = [a | a <-[1..div x 2], mod x a == 0] ++ [x]
    | otherwise = compdivides (abs x)
```

I understand that if x is positive we do the 3rd line otherwise the 4th line.

In the third line we check whether mod x a == 0 only then do we do everything else.

However, I cannot seem to understand this part `a <-[1..div x 2]` What exactly happens here?

Also, why do we do this at the end `++ [x]` ? What exactly are we doing here anyways?

```
itemTotal :: [(String, Float)] -> [(String, Float)]
itemTotal [] = []
itemTotal [x] = [x]
```

I am having some trouble with this as well.
I understand that if the list is empty we simply return an empty list.

However, what are we saying here? `itemTotal [x] = [x]` That if the list only has one thing we simply return that one thing?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> However, I cannot seem to understand this part `a <-[1..div x 2]` What exactly happens here?

This is a *generator* of the list comprehension. The list comprehension:

```
[ a | a <- [1 .. div x 2 ], mod x a == 0 ]
```

will evaluate such that `a` takes each item in the list (so *1, 2, …, x/2*), and in case `mod x a == 0` (`x` is dividable by `a`), it will add `a` to the list.

> Also, why do we do this at the end `++ [x]` ? What exactly are we doing here anyways?

It appends `x` at the end of the list. This is done because a number `x` is always dividable by itself (`x`), since the `a <- [1 .. div x 2]` stops at `div x 2`, it will never check if `x` divides `x`.

The function will get stuck in an infinite loop for `compdivides 0`, so you might want to rewrite the function to cover this case as well.

> However, what are we saying here? `itemTotal [x] = [x]` That if the list only has one thing we simply return that one thing?

**Yes**. Usually a pattern like `itemTotal (x : xs) = x : itemTotal xs` is used where we thus return a list where `x` is the first item, and we recurse on the tail of the list `xs`.

Your `itemTotal` function however only makes a copy of the list for the first two clauses. You thus can simply define `itemTotal = id`. Likely you will need to rewrite the function to determine the total of the items in the list.